# Rails/Backbone.js login using Devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, authentication, devise

I've been tasked with refactoring the login functionality of a Rails application to use Backbone.js. The Rails app is using Devise for authentication. I'm very new to Backbone and I'm not sure of the components and functions that are required to execute this. This is what I have so far (*Disclaimer: I've been doing a good deal of copy and pasting from other portions of Backbone we currently have in this app so if something seems unecessary, it probably is)*:

.js files:

LogInTemplate.hbs:

```
<div class="span4 offset1">
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  <form class="homepage-login-form" id="login-form">

    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="input-block-level" name="email">

    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-block-level" name="password">

    <a href="/password/new" class="forgot-password" data-track="track_forgot_password">{{ forgot_password }}</a>

    <input type="checkbox" id"remeber-me" name="{{ remember_me }}">

    <label name="remember-user">Keep me logged in</label>

    <div class="control-group error-group"></div>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-primary">

  </form>

  <button class="icon-cross_mark hidden-phone"></button>

</div>
```

log_in.js:

```
window.LogIn = {


'models': {},
  'collections': {},
  'views': {},
  'routers': {},
  'mixins': {},
  'init': function(data) {
    this.router = new LogIn.routers.LogInRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
  }
}

_.extend(LogIn, Backbone.Events);
```

LogInRouter.js:

```
LogIn.routers.LogInRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  'routes': {
    '': 'index'
  },

  'views': {},

  'index': function() {
    var router = this;
    router.views.activeUsersView = new LogIn.views.ActiveUsersView();
    router.views.logInView = new LogIn.views.LogInView();
  },


});
```

UsersSessionModel.js:

```
LogIn.models.UserSessionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  'url': '/',

  'defaults': {
    'title': 'Welcome back to This Application',
    'email': '',
    'password': '',
    'password_retreive': 'Forgot your password?',
    'keep_logged_in': 'Keep me logged in'
  }

});
```

LogInView.js

```
LogIn.views.LogInView = Backbone.View.extend({
  'events': {
    'submit form': 'login'
  },

  'el': '.login-container',

  'template': HandlebarsTemplates['log_in/templates/LogInTemplate'],

  'model': new LogIn.models.UserSessionModel(),

  'initialize': function() {

    view.model.fetch({
      'success': function() {
        view.render();
        view.listenTo(view.model, 'change', view.render);
      }
    });
  },

  'render': function() {
    var view = this;
    var viewData = {
      'title': view.model.get('title'),
      'email': view.model.get('email'),
      'password': view.model.get('password'),
      'password_retreive': view.model.get('password_retreive'),
      'keep_logged_in': view.model.get('keep_logged_in'),
      'log_in_btn': view.model.get('log_in_btn')
    };

    view.$el.html(view.template(viewData));
  }

});
```

Rails files:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  layout 'home'
  before_filter :set_cms_content
  before_filter :set_first_login_flag, :only => [:create]

  respond_to :json

  def new
    @user_count = Rails.cache.fetch("current_total_user_count", :expires_in => 1.hour) do
      (User.count / 100) * 100
    end
    super
  end

  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)

    render :json => {:success => true, :successUrl => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)}, :status => :ok
  end

  def failure
    render :json => {:success => false, :error => I18n.t('devise.failure.invalid') }, :status => :unprocessable_entity
  end

private

  def set_first_login_flag
    flash[:is_first_login] = true
  end

  def set_cms_content
    last_update = CmsPage.maximum(:updated_at)
    slug = 'landing-page'

    if last_update.present?
      cache_key = "cms_pages/#{slug}/#{last_update.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}"

      @landing_page = Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
        CmsPage.find_by_slug!(slug)
      end
    else
      @landing_page = CmsPage.find_by_slug!(slug)
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
WebApp::Application.routes.draw do

 #removed registration routes, only focusing on login right now

  devise_scope :user do
    root to: 'devise/sessions#new'
    get :login, :to => 'users/logins#new'
    post :login, :to => 'users/logins#create'
    post 'register/get_started', :as => 'registration/get_started', :to => 'users/registrations#get_started'
  end

end
```

Questions I have:

- Should I have two separate models, one for the login view information and one for the new_user_session route?
- Do I need to create `success` and `error` functions in my LogInView.js if I already have them in my sessions Rails controller?

  - Should I be using a gem or plug-in to make this easier (such as backbone-forms: https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms)?

I've looked around for tutorials on this with little success. Any help would be super appreciated. Thank you!